# Changing the size of struct after declared

Tags: c, arrays, struct, resize, size

I have a code contains this structure

```
struct mystruct{
  int a;
  int array[1];
};
```

Directly, after running the code
I mean I will not declare any variable of that structure,the user will enter a number, for example 6.
What I want is to know how I can change the size of that structure.

Like I declared on this form

```
struct mystruct{
  int a;
  int array[6];
};
```

Then I use normally, like this:

```
struct mystruct var;
//I do not want to add any code here, to appropriate new form
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
  var.array[i]=0;
```

Comment: `int array[];` then create by malloc in C99.

Comment: I do not want to reserve every time I declare a new variable

Comment: Your wish will not be obtained in C.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you actually want to change the size of the `struct` or of an array the struct points to? Your question and your comments contradict each other.

Comment: @Olaf You are right,I want to change the size of the struct,For change the size of array.

Comment: @Olaf But if you have any technique to change the size of array in struct.
In order to become when I declare a new variable, the variable contains the new size of array.
Tell me about

Comment: So, the best is to get along with _flexible array members_. You can't have the cake and eat it, too! Every dynamic data-structure requires dynamic memory allocation (doesn't that sound logical?). This is true for C++, too. Although it might be hidden by a class. In C you can hide that  in a function for instance.

Comment: You should get the terms right: What do you mean by "_declare_ a new variable"? Where, when? C and C++ do not allow to _declare_ varibales at run-time. They do not even allow to _define_ them at run-time. The only thing you can _allocate_ at run-time are objects (not directly affilated to OOP-objects!). In C, you `malloc` them with a pointer pointing to this.

Comment: I have a object named person, each person has array.in first I don't know the size of array because the user will enter it,Then I use the object normally and the size of array will stay constant at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do something like this in straight C (as opposed to C++) is to have just a pointer member in the struct, to point to the array, and then another member of the struct to indicate the size.  This generally requires users of the struct to malloc() the array as needed, and to also set the size member to match.  Something like:

```
struct mystruct
{
  int size;
  int *array;
};
```

and:

```
struct mystruct var;
var.array = malloc(6 * sizeof(int));
var.size = 6;

for (int i = 0; i < var.size; i++)
    var.array[i] = 0;
```

Another common paradigm is a [linked list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html).

Of course, in C++ you could just use a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: I said 
struct mystruct var;
//************* I do not want to add any code here,to appropriate new form 
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
var.array[i]=0;

Comment: I understand what you WANT to do, but you have to do something.

Comment: in your approach, `int array[];` should be `int *array;` [Test code](http://ideone.com/ekwSHd)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change an already declared struct, but you can make a new one as you want by modifying the program. You can't change data structures used in the program on the fly while it is running.

Comment: I said
"Directly, after running the code I mean I will not declare any variable of that structure" +
How can I make a new one and the program is running

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the declaration of the struct but if it is a variable length array within a struct that you want you do have an option.  Declare your struct as:

```
struct mystruct{
  int a;
  int array[0];
};
```

And then when you want to create an instance with `n` elements in the array do the following:

```
struct mystruct *a = malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct) + n * sizeof(int));
```

This will create a memory region large enough to hold the struct and an array of length `n`.  You can then use the array just as you would any other array:

```
a->array[1] = 5;
```

(this example assumes the array has at least 2 elements)

To accomplish what you have in your code example you would want to do something like this:

```
struct mystruct *var = malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct) + 6 * sizeof(int));
for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
  var->array[i]=0;
}
```

Comment: I think it's simpler to create the mystruct object on the stack, and then malloc just the "array" member.  But this would work.

Comment: @DanKorn This is a very common approach, see http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/usb.h#L1446

Comment: It may be a common approach.  But I think the link you posted actually supports my way of doing it.  The only reference to malloc() in there is about the transfer_buffer member, and the comment says to malloc() just that member, and then set the transfer_buffer_length member to match.  There's nothing in there that suggests your approach of using malloc() to create the larger struct urb.

Comment: The exact lines of code that allocate the struct and the array elements (specifically 68-70): http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/core/urb.c#L64

Comment: Okay, that's a better example.  Just the header didn't really demonstrate that by itself.

Comment: Although it's not obvious how to know how many items there are in the array after the containing struct has been created.

Comment: If you need to keep track of that its trivial, if you don't then you don't have to

Comment: I know this option is flexible array member
But I do not want to reserve every time I declare a new variable

Comment: That is not a VLA, but a _flexible array member_. But the member is defined without size: `[]`. Zero-length arrays as you use are gcc-specific and deprecated since C99.

Comment: @DanKorn: Why is allocating/freeing a single object more complicated than two linked objects?

Comment: It's not.  There are pros and cons to both approaches.